# Portainer compose error failed to deploy a stack volumes must be a string, number, boolean or null

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, portainer

I am trying to deploy below stack in Portainer.io.

```
version: '3'
services:
 app:
  image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
   - "80:80"
   - "81:81"
   - "443:443"
  environment:
   DB_MYSQL_HOST: "db"
   DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
   DB_MYSQL_USER: "admin"
   DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: "adminpwd"
   DB_MYSQL_NAME: "nginx"
   volumes:
    - '/mnt/nginx/data:/data'
    - '/mnt/nginx/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt'
 db:
  image: 'jc21/mariadb-aria:latest'
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'adminpwd'
   MYSQL_DATABASE: 'nginx'
   MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'adminpwd'
  volumes:
   - '/mnt/nginx/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
```

**Issue:**

But I am getting this below error,

> Deployment error
> failed to deploy a stack: services.app.environment.volumes must be a string, number, boolean or null

**Question:**

I tried to change the format of volumes to different things but with no luck. What is wrong with this compose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volumes are at the environment variables indentation level, and it is of type list. So you need to indent the app volume as in db service and it should work.

```
version: '3'
services:
 app:
  image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
   - "80:80"
   - "81:81"
   - "443:443"
  environment:
   DB_MYSQL_HOST: "db"
   DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
   DB_MYSQL_USER: "admin"
   DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: "adminpwd"
   DB_MYSQL_NAME: "nginx"
  volumes:
   - '/mnt/nginx/data:/data'
   - '/mnt/nginx/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt'
 db:
  image: 'jc21/mariadb-aria:latest'
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'adminpwd'
   MYSQL_DATABASE: 'nginx'
   MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'adminpwd'
  volumes:
   - '/mnt/nginx/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
```